# Where garbage Collector is in V8 sources?

Tags: v8

I am curious about various implementations of Garbage Collector libraries. And I wanted to take a look on the implementation done by V8 developers. But browsing through code I do not understand where it is in the source tree? Can I get a list of files for GC implementation? Can I use them separately for my hobby projects?

in `v8globals.h` I found this definition:

```
enum GarbageCollector { SCAVENGER, MARK_COMPACTOR };
```

But it does not look like a class or function API.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following files: heap-inl.h, heap.h, heap.cc, incremental-marking-inl.h, incremental-marking.h, incremental-marking.cc, objects-visiting-inl.h, objects-visiting.h, objects-visiting.cc, global-handles.h, global-handles.cc and so on.

The license is [BSD 3](http://opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause), so you can use it separately for your projects if you meet the BSD license conditions. Basically retain the copyright headers and don't say that Google endorses your project. IANAL.